# How do we represent the Patient's room number in a FHIR resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Looking at the FHIR documentation for Patient resource https://www.hl7.org/fhir/patient.html I can't find a way to specify a Patient's room number as it pertains to an organization (facility) that they may be associated to. I found the Location resource type  https://www.hl7.org/fhir/location.html#Location but don't see how to associated that with a Patient.

Thoughts?

Comment: I too, a complete stranger, would also like to know this.  upvote!

Answer (score 4):

The linkage would be through the Encounter resource.

Answer (score 1):

In v0.0.82 spec on the HL7.org website, the Encounter resource has a set of optional Hospitalization fields. Those in turn can point to Accommodation. One of the Accommodation fields is called 'bed', and refers to a location.

The "Current Build" documentation on github (http://hl7-fhir.github.io/encounter.html), has the Encounter directly referencing a more generic Location. But I've never been able to figure out how to reference these current builds by version number or time-date stamp, and thus: I don't know how long this 2nd paragraph of my reply will remain true/valid.

Comment: `location` seems to be in v0.0.82 and the latest build, but I think it refers to where the "encounter" happened.  Also, the latest build seems to be missing the `hospitalization` -> `accomodation`.